# Options other than master-master replication?

Tags: amazon-ec2, replication, amazon-rds

I want to migrate an EC2 instance of MySQL 5.5 to, at least, MySQL 5.6 (ideally to MariaDB 10,x) on RDS. Naturally, I'm going to use replication to do that. Part of the procedure requires a master-master setup between EC2-Mysql and RDS-Mysql and I don't think that's doable (been trying for awhile).

The reason for the master-master setup is this: Once the application is pointing to the RDS endpoint, I'd like any changes made to the RDS database to be replicated to the EC2 database in case we decide to rollback to using the EC2 instance. The MM setup won't be for long; probably overnight at most. And I can't think of a reason to roll back to using the EC2 instance, but I'm overly paranoid when it comes to production data.

Is it possible to have a master-master setup with EC2 and RDS? Some sites say "no", others, "yes". I've been trying but keep running into problems (internal timestamp formats, lack of STATEMENT based replication on RDS, etc.).

If I can't do an MM replication, is there another way for me to be able to roll back JIC?

Oh, and I can't use AWS' Database Migration Service since I have a couple thousand databases to migrate (don't ask).

Comment: Master/master isn't officially supported, but it should be quite possible to implement.  A bigger problem is the inconsistency between server versions.  (Also, you should never use statement-based logging, ever, ever.)

Comment: The only reason I wanted to use statement based logging is to minimize internal format differences, but yeah, the inconsistency is what's killing me.